# Blured background image with css

Tags: css, image, background, blur

Is there anyway to blur an image with `CSS`, specially for backgrounds?

Comment: You could always simulate it by introducing a new element and applying a wide `text-shadow`. I'm not sure if that's what I would recommend, though...

Comment: try `filter: blur(5px);` (also in -webkit, -ms etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.
You can use two different backgrounds, one with sharp color (the main picture) and another blurred picture:

```
body  {
  background: url(images/bg-solid.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#page-wrap {
  background: url(images/bg-blurry.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  width: 500px; margin: 40px auto;
}
```

[To see the detailed tutorial click here](http://css-tricks.com/blurry-background-effect/)

**EDIT:**
For an image you can use svg filters as below:
The `<feGaussianBlur>` element is used to create blur effects:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3"
  fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

- The id attribute of the  element defines a unique name for
  the filter
- The blur effect is defined with the  element
- The in="SourceGraphic" part defines that the effect is created for
  the entire element
- The stdDeviation attribute defines the amount of the blur
- The filter attribute of the  element links the element to the
  "f1" filter
  [See here for detailed explanation](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/SVGOpen2010/Filters2.htm)

Comment: Also a (rather beautiful) alternative from [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/complexspiral/glassy.html).

Comment: I mean with one image. I have an image and I want it to be seemed blurry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is the way of blur images by the filter, you can read more about them here in the link. BUT they do not work properly for all browsers yet! And I didn't find a way to make them work for the background image.

[Check this](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through **CSS**.

You have to process the image using a server-side language and generate a blurry one and then use it in the CSS backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for your clean out answer ;)

Comment: @MSajjadi, I can make my answer better, by giving you a PHP solution, if you like.

Comment: It's possible without any server-side affects.

Comment: @علیرضا, I mentioned about CSS, not serverside and definitely not SVG